# IOS Core magical record return empty Array

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Hi I'm using magical record to work with `CoreData`. My data structure is `ArticleCategory` which has property `category` and `module`. `ArticleCategory` can contain many `Article` object. Data is fetch from JSON from server. I want to create an array contain all `ArticleCategory` and each `ArticleCategory` contain all `Article` belong to it

Here is my function to create and array from JSON and also create entity

```
    + (NSArray *)articleItemsForJSON:(NSDictionary *)jsonItems module:(NSString *)moduleName
    {
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSArray *sortedCategories = jsonItems[@"keys"];

        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

        for (NSString *category in sortedCategories) {

            ArticleCategory *articleCategory = [ArticleCategory MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:@"module" withValue:moduleName inContext:localContext];

            if (articleCategory.category ==nil) {
                articleCategory.category = category;
            }

            NSMutableArray *articles = [NSMutableArray array];
            [jsonItems[category] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id articleJSON, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

                Article *article = [Article MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:@"name" withValue:articleJSON[@"Name"] inContext:articleCategory.managedObjectContext];

                if (article.buttonType==nil){
                                    [article setOrderingValue:idx];
                    [article updateWithApiRepresentation:articleJSON];
                }
                [articles addObject:article];

            }];

            [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

            [articleCategory setArticles:[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:articles]];
            [items addObject:articleCategory];

        };
        return items;
    }
```

I don't know why it is not working (return empty items)

If I do this way. It work find (but does app will save duplicate record to CoreData). Any way to fix this problem. Thanks!

```
 + (NSArray *)articleItemsForJSON:(NSDictionary *)jsonItems module:(NSString *)moduleName
    {
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSArray *sortedCategories = jsonItems[@"keys"];

        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

        for (NSString *category in sortedCategories) {

            ArticleCategory *articleCategory = [[ArticleCategory alloc] initWithEntity:[ArticleCategory entityInManagedObjectContext:localContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];

            articleCategory.module = moduleName;
            articleCategory.category = category;

            NSMutableArray *articles = [NSMutableArray array];
            [jsonItems[category] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id articleJSON, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                Article *article = [[Article alloc] initWithEntity:[Article entityInManagedObjectContext:localContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];

                [article updateWithApiRepresentation:articleJSON];
                [articles addObject:article];

            }];

            [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

            [articleCategory setArticles:[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:articles]];
            [items addObject:articleCategory];

        };
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: How are you saving anything if your objects aren't inserted in a context? `insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil`

Comment: hi sorry the 2nd function only return the correct items. did not do anything with saving coredata. My problem is why the 1st not working!